# A proof of Hilbert's basis theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I tried to prove the Hilbert's Basis Theorem and don't know if it is correct or not.

> **Hilbert's Basis Theorem.** If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $R[X]$ is a Noetherian ring.

*Proof*:
We know that $R$ is Noetherian iff every ideal is finitely generated i.e. for any ideal $I \subset R, \ \exists \ a_{1},\dots, a_{n} \in R$ such that $I=\langle a_{1},\dots, a_{k}\rangle:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}Ra_{i}$.

I'd like to prove that if $J$ is an ideal of $R[T]$, then it must have the form $I[T]\setminus J'$ with some ideal $I \subseteq R$ and $J'$ consisting of polynomials with coefficients in $I$, but it has a maximal degree (this is because if $J$ is an ideal of $R[T]$, that doesn't mean it must have polynominals of degree $1;...$ up to some $n$ but it must have $0$ since it is an additive subgroup).

We are going to assume that this ideal $J$ is not of the form that we've described. Now, since $J $ is an ideal of $R[T]$, $\forall f \in R[T]$, and, $g \in J, fg \in J$ but we could choose any $f$ and $g$ that we want, so $J$ can't have finite order (PS: If $R$ is not an integral domain, we should still get the same thing since if we choose $f \in R[T]$ such that the last coefficient is $1_{R}$ and we have any other $a \in R \backslash \{0\}$, then $a *1_{R}=a \neq 0$).

But now, a polynominal in $R[T]$ could have any coefficients in $R$ and so if we define$f(T):= \sum_{\nu=0}^{n}r_{\nu}T^{\nu} \in R[T]$ and $g(T):=\sum_{\nu=0}^{m}a_{\nu}T^{\nu} \in J \subseteq R[T]$, then: $(fg)(T)=\sum_{\nu=0}^{n} \sum_{\mu=0}^{m}  r_{\nu} a_{\mu} T^{\nu+\mu} \in J$, but since $J$ is also an additive subgroup of $R[T]$, all the coefficients of the polynominals in it form an additive subgroup of $R$ and hence they form an ideal.

Therefore, we get that $J$ must have the form $J:=I[T]\backslash J'$ as described at the beggining of this part and if we want to write it as a set (to make no confusion on why we chose that $J'$), $J:=\{0;f;...\}$, where $deg(f)=n+1$. Let's call $n+1$ the minimal degree of $J$.

$The\, second\, part$: In this part we want to prove that $J$ is finitely generated by using the fact that $I$ is so.
We first see that every polynominal in $f \in J$ has the form: $f:=\sum_{\nu=n+1}^{n+1+m}a_{\nu}T^{\nu}=T^{n+1}(a_{n+1}+...+a_{n+m+1}T^{m})$. This tells us that every polynominal in $J$ is just a polynominal in $I[T]$ multiplied by that extra $T^{n+1}$. Now we will do induction on the degree of any $f \in I[T]$ to prove that $I[T]$ is finitely generated which implies that so is $J$(note that the induction part on the smallest degree of $f \in I[T]$ is the same thing as the induction on the minimal degree of $J$):

$P(0)$: For $deg(f)=0 $ we get that $f$ could be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}a_{i}$ since $I=<a_{1};...;a_{k}>$. So $I[T]$ has the form $<a_{1};...;a_{k};f_{1};...;f_{l}>$ where $f_{1};...;f_{l}$ are polynominals but we don't know if $l \longmapsto \infty$ or not.

$P(1)$: For $deg(f)=1$, we define $f$ as $f:=aT+b \in I[T]$ and the idea is similar as for in $P(0)$( write a $a$ and $b$ as in $P(0)$).

$P(m) \Longrightarrow P(m+1)$: Let's assume that every polynominal of degree $m$ is finitely generated, namely $f:=\sum_{i=1}^{l'}p_{i}g_{i} \in I[T]$, where whe chose the polynominals $g_{i}$ and $l'$ for abreviation( $I[T]=<g_{1};...;g_{l'}>$) and $p_{i} \in R[T]$. Now let's take the polynominal $q \in I[T]$ of degree $m+1$ such that $q:=f+aT^{m+1}$ but $aT^{m+1}=aT^{m}T$ and $deg(aT^{m})=m$ and hence $aT^{m}$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^{l'}p'_{i}g_{i}$ with $p'_{i} \in R[T]$ and hence $aT^{m+1}$ has the form $ \sum_{i=1}^{l'}(Tp'_{i})g_{i}$. Hence, $q$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^{l'}p_{i}g_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{l'}(Tp'_{i})g_{i}= \sum_{i=1}^{l'}(p_{i}+Tp'_{i})g_{i}            $.

Hence, since the induction holds, this concludes the proof of the Hilbert's basis theorem

Please tell me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: I've edited the first few sentences of the post.  I'm lost at the second paragraph in the proof.  I don't understand it.

Comment: In the second part we have proved that $I[T]$ is finitely generated and wrote it as $I[T]=<g_{1};...;g_{l'}>$ but  saying that every polynominal in $J$ is a polynominal in $I[T]$ multiplied by $T^{n+1}$ is equivalent by saying that $J= T^{n+1}I[T] =  T^{n+1}   <g_{1};...;g_{l'}>=  <  T^{n+1}    g_{1};...;   T^{n+1}       g_{l'}> $ and thus $J$ is finitely generated and since every ideal in $R[T]$ has the form of $J$ we get that all of the ideals of $R[T]$ are finitely generated and hence $R[T]$ is Noetherian. 
If there is still something you don't understand please tell me that part.

Comment: Mario, the reader should not have have to refer to the second part to understand the first paragraph.  Please rewrite it for reader  understanding.

Comment: Sorry but I understood it as the second part.

Comment: Wait a few minutes until I explain the second paragraph.

Comment: Let $J$ be an ideal of $R[T]$. Let's choose now two polynominals, $f \in J$ and $g \in R[T]$ and write them as $f:=\sum_{\nu=0}^{m}a_{\nu}T^{\nu}\,and\,g:=\sum_{\nu=0}^{p}b_{\nu}T^{\nu}$. Since $J$ is an ideal, $fg \in J \Leftrightarrow \sum_{\nu=0}^{m}\sum_{\mu=0}^{p}a_{\nu}b_{\nu}T^{\nu + \mu}$ so we notice that since the polynominal $fg$ is still in $J$, the coefficients of all polynominals in $J$ form an ideal of $R$. Hence the most natural way to think of an ideal of $R[T]$ is $I[T]$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ but not every ideal of $R[T]$ has this form. continued...

Comment: ... The reason that it doesn't have that form is that no one tells us that there must be polynominals in $R[T]$ that have order $0$ (a polynominal has order n if it has the form $a_{n}T^{n}+...+a_{m}T^{m}$). To convince you that there don't need to be polynominals of order $0$, define $J$ as in the proof, namely $J:={0;f;...}$ (this $f$ doesn't have anything to do with the $f$ we chose in the first part of this comment) with $f$ being the polynominal that has the smallest order and let's define it as $f:=a_{n}T^{n}+...+a_{m}T^{m}$. continued...

Comment: ...Note that there could be other polynominals in $J$ of the same order as $f$. We just chose an arbitrary $f$ with smallest order. If you now choose any other $g \in J$ and add it to $f$, the order of $f+g$ is still $n$. This tells us that $J$ is closed under addition and hence an abelian group. Multiplying $f$ by any $h \in R[T]$ will not make the order smaller, i.e. the order of $fg$ is still greater or equal than $n$ and hence $J$ is an ideal since $J$ has the coefficients of an ideal $I \subseteq R$, we have $J \subseteq I[T]$ and by denoting $J':=\{q \in I[T] | o(q)<n; q\neq 0\}$cont...

Comment: ... we finally have that $J=I[T]\backslash J'$.                                                                                    I know this was a long explanation because it's quite hard to understand that part by just reading it. Hope it helped